# Remote Validation On Nested ViewModels With __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken, remote-validation

I have a viewmodel class that called "LoginIndexViewModel" for use on login razor page, containing login, signin & forget password forms. It contains several properties, each of which is a viewmodel separately. Here is the "LoginIndexViewModel" viewmodel:

```
public class LoginIndexViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel Login { get; set; }

    public SignUpViewModel SignUp { get; set; }

    public ForgetPasswordViewModel ForgetPassword { get; set; }
}
```

On "SignUpViewModel" there is a property that has remote validation and I want to check anti-forgery-token before action method call. Here is the body of the "SignUpViewModel":

```
public class SignUpViewModel
{
    .
    .
    .

    [Display(Name = "Email *")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email Is Required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address.")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address.")]
    [Remote("CheckUsername", "Account", ErrorMessage = "The Email Address Have Already Registered.", HttpMethod = "POST", **AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I used [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute above the action method "CheckUsername" and @Html.AntiForgeryToken() on the razor view such as the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxOnly]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public virtual async Task<JsonResult> CheckUsername([Bind(Prefix = "SignUp.UserName")]string userName)
{
    return Json(await _userManager.CheckUsername(username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

razor view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.ActionNames.Register, MVC.Account.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegisterForm", @class = "m-login__form m-form", role = "form" }))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   .
   .
   .
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SignUp.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email *", autocomplete = "off", @Value = "" })
       <span class="helper">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SignUp.UserName)</span>
   </div>
   .
   .
   .
 }
```

The problem is that remote validation call throws the exception: **'The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.'**

According to the Mozilla debugger tool, I found that CheckUsername calls with 'SignUp.__RequestVerificationToken' parameter instead of '__RequestVerificationToken' therefore it raise an exception.

Anyone knows that what happened and why __RequestVerificationToken is not providing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of the prefix to properties defined in `AdditionalFields` is by design, and is added by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. The relevant code is that adds the prefix is in the `adapters.add("remote", ["url", "type", "additionalfields"], function (options) {` method.

There are numerous options to solve your problem

Create your own custom (say) `[ValidateAntiForgeryTokenWithPrefix]` attribute based on the existing source code, but modify to strip any prefix from the request (not recommended)

Make your own ajax call, rather than using the `[Remote]` attribute - i.e. handle the `.blur()` event of the textbox to call the server method, passing both the value and the token, and update the placeholder generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in the success callback, and handle the `.keyup()` event to clear any message. This does have a performance advantage because after initial validation, the `remote` rule makes an ajax call on every `keyup()` event, so it can result in a lot of server and database calls.

However the easiest solution would be to create 3 partials based on `LoginViewModel`, `SignUpViewModel` and `ForgetPasswordViewModel` and call then from the main view using `@Html.Partial()`, for example

_SignUpViewModel.cshtml

```
@model SignUpViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.ActionNames.Register, MVC.Account.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegisterForm", @class = "m-login__form m-form", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email *", autocomplete = "off" })
        <span class="helper">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </span>
    </div>
    ....
}
```

and in the main view

```
@model LoginIndexViewModel
....
@Html.Partial("_SignUpViewModel", Model.SignUp)
.... // ditto for Login and ForgetPassword properties
```

You can then omit the `[Bind(Prefix = "SignUp.UserName")]` from the `CheckUsername()` method.

Alternatively you make the main view based on say `LoginViewModel`, and then use `@Html.Action()` to call `[ChildActionOnly]` methods that return partial views of the other 2 forms.

Having said that, a user will only ever use the `SignUp` form once, and may never use the `ForgetPassword` form, so including all that extra html is just degrading performance, and it would be better to have links to redirect them to separate pages for `SignUp` and `ForgetPassword`, or if you want them in the same page, then load partials for them on demand using ajax.

As a side note, you do not need the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` argument in your `return Json(...)` (its a `[HttpPost]` method), and you should never set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods.